# Understanding rails delegate method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn about delegate method that Rails provides out of the box. Here is what I'm trying to do. So, I have `Accounts` that have_many `Tasks`. So I'm trying to get the task count for accounts and here is how I'm currently doing it:

```
def total_tasks
  tasks.count
end
```

Pretty standard thing. But I'm trying to move this method to a delegate method. I've tried this but it's not working

```
 delegate :count, to: :task, prefix: "total"
```

That didn't work and I really didn't expect it do. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: I think your first solution is far better than a delegation as it adds readability. `Accounts#total_tasks` makes much more sense than `Accounts#total_count` (the delegation method) where I am unsure what I am counting. Additionally I agree with @max `size` is a much better choice of method than `count` to avoid unnecessary DB hits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delegate :count, to: :tasks, prefix: "total"
```

This is just meta programming that creates a method:

```
def total_count
  tasks.send(:count)
end
```

This is not really a good fit for delegate though as you should be using `size` instead of `count` as the latter always causes a DB query even if the association has been eager loaded.

```
def tasks_total
  tasks.size # prevents n+1 query issue.
end
```

Why you would want to create a method for this is beyond me though as its actually one more character to type.

Comment: technically it would be `total_count` with an underscore but I agree with your complete sentiment